# 80% of mobile recharges on girls' phones are done by their boyfriends - How do I say that?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In eight out of ten cases, mobile recharges (top up recharge) on girls' mobile phones are done by their boyfriends. Now, I want to tell this in this way...

> 80% of mobile recharges on girls' phones are done by their boyfriends

But if I rethink it, it also means that 80% of total amount paid for single recharge is being paid by their boyfriends. Said that, if the recharge is of INR 100, INR 80 will be paid by their boyfriends.

How do I say that quoted sentence without this ambiguity?

Answer (score 4):

Without ambiguity, you can state it as:

> 80% of mobile recharges on girls' phones are done by their boyfriends.

While it *would* be possible to read this as "80% of every recharge is paid for by the boyfriend", this is an *unlikely interpretation*.

First of all, it is kind of hard to imagine, for anybody even remotely familiar with the concept of pre-paid phone charges, that whenever you recharge your credit, you pay 20% and someone else pays 80%.

Secondly, by using the *plural* form, *recharges*, you clearly refer to the individual actions of recharging one's credit, indicating that you are probably talking about "80% of the occurrences of someone recharging their credit".

Compare to a similar sentence (which I am making up, but might appear in a news article):

> Up to 20% of exported cigarettes are stolen before they arrive.

I don't think anybody would read this as 20% of every cigarette being removed illegally.

Actually, **if** you would want to suggest that 80% of every recharge is paid for by the boyfriend, you would have to explicitly say so, because it will not be understood from the sentence as you wrote it. You'd have to change it into something like:

> 80% of every mobile recharge on girls' phones **is** by their boyfriends.

Changing 'are' to the singular 'is' indicates that we are now talking about a percentage of an individual recharge.

Comment: Yes, I was quite cautious writing it plural! :) thanks for confirming. +1